# Playa parent multiple entry_ids

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic

Is there a way to select parents from multiple child entry ids? For example, I have a blog channel with a playa relationship,via a blog_staff field, to a people channel (to identify authors of blog entries) and a team channel with a playa relationship, via a team_members field,  to people as well (to group them into teams). I tried to query for blog entries of multiple people but seem to be limited to only one.

I tried the playa field feeding the people entry_ids through an embed to a parents field to grab the associated blog entries:

```
{team_members}
    {embed="includes/.bp_by_staff" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
{/team_members}
```

The .bp_by_staff template trying to use those people entry_ids to look up their blog posts:

```
{exp:playa:parents channel="blog"  entry_id="{embed:people}"}
    {title}
{/exp:playa:parents}
```

Now, if {embed:people} is just one entry_id, say "18", this works great, the blog posts get found. But if {embed:people} yields multiple entry ids (the team has more than one person), say "18|29", it doesn't work.

Looking through the profiler for the generated sql of the failing case, one can see why.  It seems like including more than one entry_id breaks the sql query which uses "=" rather than " in " for the where clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(rel.parent_entry_id) AS entry_id
FROM exp2_playa_relationships rel 
WHERE rel.child_entry_id = 18|29
```

If the where clause were using "in" as in `WHERE rel.child_entry_id in (18, 29)` the query works correctly.

Anyone find a workaround for getting results for multiple entry_ids ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the coparents tag? Isn't this what it's for?

Answer (score 0):

**Revising my answer**, The multiple entry_ids issue *was* addressed, in [version 4.2](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/changelog.html#playa-4-2).  Upgrading Playa seems to resolve it. Templates used:

```
{embed="includes/.nested-entries" entry_ids="{team_members:child_ids}"}
```

and .nested_entries embed would take the entry_id and look up the blog written by that "people" entry:

```
{exp:playa:parents entry_id="{embed:entry_ids}"  channel="blog"  field="blog_staff"  orderby="date"
limit="10" disable="member_data|categories" paginate="bottom" }

    {title}

 {pagination_links}

{/exp:playa:parents}
```

Side point, needing paginagion links, i made sure they weren't disabled by explicitly specifying what to disable.